# ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for jquery Foundation

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, zurb-foundation, bower

I am trying to install Foundation but its continuously giving me conflict with Jquery

```
λ bower install foundation
bower foundation#x              cached https://github.com/zurb/bower-foundation.git#5.5.1
bower foundation#x            validate 5.5.1 against https://github.com/zurb/bower-foundation.git#x
bower foundation#*              cached https://github.com/zurb/bower-foundation.git#5.5.1
bower foundation#*            validate 5.5.1 against https://github.com/zurb/bower-foundation.git#*
bower jquery#>= 2.1.0           cached https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#2.1.3
bower jquery#>= 2.1.0         validate 2.1.3 against https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#>= 2.1.0
bower modernizr#>= 2.7.2        cached https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr.git#2.8.3
bower modernizr#>= 2.7.2      validate 2.8.3 against https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr.git#>= 2.7.2
bower jquery.cookie#~1.4.0      cached https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie.git#1.4.1
bower jquery.cookie#~1.4.0    validate 1.4.1 against https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie.git#~1.4.0
bower fastclick#>=0.6.11        cached https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick.git#1.0.6
bower fastclick#>=0.6.11      validate 1.0.6 against https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick.git#>=0.6.11
bower jquery-placeholder#~2.0.7 cached https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder.git#2.0.9
bower jquery-placeholder#~2.0.7         validate 2.0.9 against https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder.git#~2.0.7
bower                                  ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for jquery
```

My bower.json file is this

```
{
  "name": "refactor",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~1.11.1",
    "raphael": "1.3.x",
    "font-awesome": "~4.3.0",
    "foundation": "x"
  }
}
```

Comment: use "jquery": ">= 2.0.0"

Comment: I just removed JQuery. Now its getting from Foundation, I don't know its right practice or not

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `resolutions` in your `bower.json`

```
{
  "name": "refactor",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~1.11.1",
    "raphael": "1.3.x",
    "font-awesome": "~4.3.0",
    "foundation": "x"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": "~1.11.1"
  }
}
```

This will force bower to use that specific version of jQuery.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much!

Comment: This worked for me! The error messages I was getting from the npm debug log (and somewhat more cryptically in the console) indicated what version of jQuery was needed. This was while provisioning vagrant for a Drupal 8 site. Much thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Best way to start with is to do

```
bower cache clean
```

After that when you do

`bower install` it will ask you

`'Unable to find a suitable version for <Your Dependency Name>, please choose one:` ,

then you can enter `!1` 
or `!2` , or whatever suits your needs the best.

This essentially adds the resolution block into bower.json as mentioned by @esbanarango  but it just gives more control and understanding over what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this for the Jquery version:

```
"jquery": ">= 2.0.0"
```

However I think you would only need Foundation as a dependency:

[image]

or:

```
{
    "name": "PROJECT_NAME",
    "dependencies": {
       "foundation": "~5.4.7"
    }
}
```

also check here for more details:

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html