# ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for polymer

Tags: npm, bower, polymer-1.0, web-component, bower-install

### When using Bower to install packages to develop Polymer (v.1.4.0) apps, and save to my `bower.json` file,

```
bower install --save GoogleWebComponents/google-map
```

**It's hit or miss when I get the error message:**

```
ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for polymer
```

**Here's the complete output:**

```
      $ bower install --save GoogleWebComponents/google-map
      bower google-map#*              cached git://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map.git#1.1.10
      bower google-map#*            validate 1.1.10 against git://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map.git
      bower tem-waypoint#^1.0.0       cached https://github.com/elegantmonkeys/tem-waypoint.git#1.0.0
      bower tem-waypoint#^1.0.0     validate 1.0.0 against https://github.com/elegantmonkeys/tem-waypoint.git#^
      bower juicy-html#^1.1.0         cached https://github.com/Juicy/juicy-html.git#1.1.0
      bower juicy-html#^1.1.0       validate 1.1.0 against https://github.com/Juicy/juicy-html.git#^1.1.0
      bower scroll-progress#^0.0.3    cached https://github.com/samiheikki/scroll-progress.git#0.0.3
      bower scroll-progress#^0.0.3  validate 0.0.3 against https://github.com/samiheikki/scroll-progress.git#^0
      bower google-apis#^1.1.1        cached git://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-apis.git#1.1.5
      bower google-apis#^1.1.1      validate 1.1.5 against git://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-apis.git.1
      bower waypoints#^4.0.0          cached https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints.git#4.0.0
      bower waypoints#^4.0.0        validate 4.0.0 against https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints.git#^4.0
      bower polymer#1.2.3             cached git://github.com/Polymer/polymer.git#1.2.3
      bower polymer#1.2.3           validate 1.2.3 against git://github.com/Polymer/polymer.git#1.2.3
      bower polymer#^1.2.1            cached git://github.com/Polymer/polymer.git#1.4.0
      bower polymer#^1.2.1          validate 1.4.0 against git://github.com/Polymer/polymer.git#^1.2.1
      bower polymer#^1.1.0            cached git://github.com/Polymer/polymer.git#1.4.0
      bower polymer#^1.1.0          validate 1.4.0 against git://github.com/Polymer/polymer.git#^1.1.0
      bower polymer#^1.2.4            cached git://github.com/Polymer/polymer.git#1.4.0
      bower polymer#^1.2.4          validate 1.4.0 against git://github.com/Polymer/polymer.git#^1.2.4
      bower polymer#^1.4.0            cached https://github.com/Polymer/polymer.git#1.4.0
      bower polymer#^1.4.0          validate 1.4.0 against https://github.com/Polymer/polymer.git#^1.4.0
      bower                        ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for polymer
```

**Here's my bower.json file:**

```
    {
      "name": "polymer-starter-kit",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "iron-elements": "PolymerElements/iron-elements#^1.0.0",
        "neon-elements": "PolymerElements/neon-elements#^1.0.0",
        "page": "visionmedia/page.js#~1.6.4",
        "paper-elements": "PolymerElements/paper-elements#^1.0.1",
        "platinum-elements": "PolymerElements/platinum-elements#^1.1.0",
        "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^1.2.0",
        "iron-swipeable-pages": "^1.2.3",
        "parallax-container": "^1.1.1",
        "juicy-html": "^1.1.0",
        "html-include": "^0.1.2",
        "scroll-progress": "^0.0.3",
        "tem-waypoint": "^1.0.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "web-component-tester": "^4.0.0"
      },
      "ignore": []
    }
```

Is there something I can do on my end to alleviate this problem? I'm having to manually drag n drop dependencies into projects and on top of that, they are not saving to my bower file (defeating the purpose of bower).

Any help would appreciated!

Comment: What version of polymer are you using?

Comment: The newest: "version": "1.4.0",

Comment: I added my bower.json above

Comment: I'm just new to using Bower, but it seems to me that this line `bower polymer#1.2.3` is the one causing problems as it seems to be indicating a specific version

Comment: Take a look at the answer [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28469163/econflict-unable-to-find-suitable-version-for-jquery-foundation), it may help you

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've played around with it a little..and it is a workaround, however it's still a manual process..or I just don't know the proper bower command to use. I want to be able to use the "bower install --save package" .. and this will auto save the to your dependencies (not the resolutions). I guess what I'm looking for now is how to "--save" to the resolutions.

Comment: @Oneezy, to save the resolution to `bower.json`, prefix the resolution selection with `!` when prompted (as instructed in the prompt).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45861497/2393789