# TFS 2015 build error

Tags: tfs-2015

I need help with my TFS 2015, I able to run build and publish in Visual Studio 2015 and when I create a build it in TFS 2015, my jquery is not completely built.

my setup in Command Line
Tool : C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm\bower.cmd
Arguments : install jquery

[Build log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqepS.jpg)

Everything works fine except the jquery only a few files and folders were created compared to build from in VS 2015.

Please let me know where I did wrongly.

Comment: Please click the failed task and share the entire log.

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution in this case [ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for jquery Foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28469163/econflict-unable-to-find-suitable-version-for-jquery-foundation):

Use `resolutions` in your `bower.json` file. For example:

```
{
  "name": "refactor",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~1.11.1",
    "raphael": "1.3.x",
    "font-awesome": "~4.3.0",
    "foundation": "x"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": "~1.11.1"
  }
}
```

This will force bower to use that specific version of jQuery.